# Autoload Classmap in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, autoloader

I have a:

```
// administration
app/controller/admin/ProjectsController.php
```

And I want use too:

```
// public in website
app/controller/ProjectsController.php
```

But, in autoload_classmap.php, it's registred like that:

```
'ProjectsController' => 'app/controller/admin/ProjectsController'
```

So, If I want one more 'ProjectsController' for public views, how I need to do? 
What is better? 2 controllers (admin and public), or one (hybrid).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should namespace your Admin controllers.

That way it'll match up to PSR and autoloader will treat them differently.

`namespace Admin;`

At the top of your admin files.

**Edit:**

It may even be worth namespacing all your controllers and models.

So for your `ProjectController` in `app\controllers` you could put

`namespace ProjectName`

Then for everything in subfolders, e.g. `app\controllers\admin`

`namespace ProjectName\Admin`

and so on for other folders, and files.

This'll reduce the likely hood of your code clashing with anything else.

**Edit: Edit:**

After namespacing classes you'll need to reference classes and functions that are outside your namespace. For example Controller belongs to the global namespace so you put \ at the start of Controller.

The documentation here should help out a lot. [PHP Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php)

Comment: Doesn't work.FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'PatrickMaciel\Admin\Controller' not found in ....

Comment: Did you do a ```composer update```? Can you also provide a paste of your controllers?

Comment: composer update, or composer dump-autoload? Update is for update (like git pull right?).

Comment: Strange. When I run composer update, composer connect with git and composer packages for check updates...

Comment: I've forked your gist and updated your code, it now all works :)

Comment: For update autoload classmap you need to run : `composer dump-autoload` as say in blue here: http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers